# IntelliJ, Maven and Java 7

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea, java-7

So I opened an existing project in IntelliJ 10.5 as a maven project.  I had first added the JDK 7 to my list of SDKs in order to try out the features.  However for some reason my mvn commands would fail, so I switched the maven runner back to 1.6.  But I'm getting a weird error where some maven commands are still being run with Java 7.

In the Maven Projects view when I right click on a lifecycle in the module and select Run Maven Build everything works correctly, however when I select Run " clean" it still uses the 1.7 JDK.  I have removed the JDK 7 from my list and now I get an error saying it can't find JRE '1.7'.

I honestly have no idea how to fix this, but if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: How do you add the JDK to your list of SDKs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the `Maven Projects` panel press the `Settings` button (or open `Settings` | `Maven` | `Runner`).

Make sure that **JRE** is set to the existing JRE configuration (1.6).

Comment: Yes it is, that is what lets me use the default Run Maven Build, but still cannot do the other options.

Comment: If you have created IDEA Run/Debug configuration for the Maven goal, it will have its own settings for the Maven runner, make sure to update the JRE for the Run configuration as well.

Comment: CrazyCoder that was the answer, for some reason it set the Run/Debug configs the first time I set the runner, but when changing it back, it did not update those.  I manually updated in the build config defaults and it works like a champ.

Comment: I tried changing the JRE for my maven runner via Run -> "Edit Configurations" and that didn't work, but once I changed it on the project level using "Settings -> Maven -> Runner", then the change worked.